# Angular 2 AOT moduleFactory.moduleType is undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I am compiling my angular 2 project AOT. When I serve the page it outputs, I get the error `moduleFactory.moduleType is undefined`. If I replace `name: moduleFactory.moduleType.name` with `name: 'someRandomString'` in my bundle.js, everything works just fine, but I don't want to manually replace that every time I deploy; what is the cause of this error and how can I fix it?